# How to stop video playing in background Nativescript -angular

Tags: nativescript

Im using video in my project ,but video is playing in background ,When i move to another component.This problem occurs only in ios ,not in android

Html

```
<VideoPlayer
src="{{videoUrl}}"
height="300"></VideoPlayer>
```

angular

```
  index:any
  videoUrl :any




  ngOnInit() {

    this.router.paramMap.subscribe(
      (response) =>{
        this.index = response.get('id')
        this.videoUrl=this.galleryService.getVideoById(this.index)
        console.log(response)

      }
    )    
  }
```

This is my code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen to [navigatingFrom](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/page#page-events) event on your current Page and call `pause()` method on the VideoPlayer.

**HTML**

```
<VideoPlayer #player
  src="{{videoUrl}}"
  height="300"></VideoPlayer>
```

**TS**

```
@ViewChild("player") player: ElementRef; 

constructor(private page: Page) { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.router.paramMap.subscribe(
     (response) => {
      this.index = response.get('id')
      this.videoUrl=this.galleryService.getVideoById(this.index)
      console.log(response)
   });
   this.page.on(Page.navigatingFromEvent, () => {
      this.player.nativeElement.pause();
   });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
 this.page.off(Page.navigatingFromEvent);
}
```

You may also use Router Events on Angular, but you might have to filter the appropriate route.